# '/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gurifuncs.h missing from glib-2.0

Tags: c++, linux, glib, juce

I try to build a cpp program with the JUCE framework and I get the error

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gurifuncs.h', needed by 'build/intermediate/Debug/include_juce_gui_extra_6dee1c1a.o'.  Stop.
```

I have glib-2.0 on the exact location but no file called gurifuncs.h only guri.h I think this is the new version of gurifuncs.h. Is this correct?

I am on manjaro Mikah latest updates installed, last update of glib in the logfiles is v2.64.4-1.

I can not downgrade glib cause everything needs to stay up to date or my system starts crashing. Is there a way to fix this? The makefile is generated with the projucer from juce.

Comment: What version are you on? Manjaro uses arch repo latest of everything. I checked github of glib and it was missing there as well

Answer (score 1):

I ran make clean and rebuilt, it correctly used the newer version of glib.